# How do i connect my server to Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, cloud, mongodb-atlas

Recently i decided to move my database from inside my server machine to the [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas) service.

Atlas provides a IP Whitelist feature which i use to remotely connect to the database cluster.

Should i plug my server application to Atlas using this feature?
What happens if my server IP changes? Is it secure?

Answer (score 1):

For a general information on how to connect to an Atlas deployment, please see [Connect to a Cluster](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/)

For connecting using a driver, please see [Connect via Driver](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/). There is an extensive list of examples using all of the officially-supported drivers.

As mentioned in the [Prerequisites section](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/connect-to-cluster/#prerequisites), you need to use SSL/TLS and IP whitelist to connect to your Atlas instance. This whitelist would need to be updated should your application server's IP changes.

The whitelist provides an additional security layer in addition to your username/password, since this list will essentially reject any connection not originating from a known IP address. It is strongly recommended to utilize this whitelist, and arguably the effort required to maintain the whitelist is comparably small to the security advantages it provides.